# Ridiculous difference in website view between "192.168.1.140" and "192.168.1.140/index.html"

Tags: html, apache, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make some website using bootstrap framework.

This is the code of first and only one page I done.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="Elektroniczna baza elementów">
<meta name="author" content="Pierwiastek">
<link rel="icon" href="images/logo.ico">
<title>Elektroniczna baza elementów</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/signin.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

```
<div class="container">
  <form class="form-signin" role="form" action="index.html" method="post">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Komputerowa Baza Elementów</h2>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required autofocus>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Hasło" required>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Zapamiętaj logowanie
    </label>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span>Zaloguj się</button>        
  </form>         
</div>
```

The problem is that glyphicon doesnt show when I type in my browser (Mozilla FF 31) 192.168.1.140 and shows when i type 192.168.1.140/index.html

On 192.168.1.140 there is my remote debian server with newest Apache, PHP5, MySQL from debian repos, and there is also Samba which give me an access from my Windows 7 desktop. I edit index.html file directly on samba folder with Notepad++

It ridiculous! There is something even worse! I can delete all body section from index.html file and refresh 192.168.1.140 site in firefox and nothing change! I still can view my singin form. Only when I type 192.168.1.140/index.html I can see the site disappear.

What is wrong? Am I think correctly that something with linux/apache config?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any option in apache httpd that would make those two URLs any different but here are some suggestions:

1) I the code above I'm missing the `<html></html>`, `<head></head>` and `<body></body>` tags, probably you just left them out for brevity.

2) you specified a relative path for `"images/logo.ico"` have you tried the full path (that is: `"/images/logo.ico"` or even `"http://<your-domain>/logo.ico"`) ?

3) When I was experimenting with icons some time ago the browser cacheing was sometimes doing funny things. Reloading was not sufficient, I had to flush the cache, and restart the browser to get reliable results.

4) the german wikipedia recommends to use three different links to satisfy all browsers:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://example.com/favicon.ico">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
<link type="image/x-icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
```

hope any of this helps

Tobi

Edit: sorry, missed the topic :( you were talking about the icon in the button.
My only guess would be that the page is cached somewhere (Browser or apache httpd). Tried restarting them both?

Comment: Yeah I was writing about icon in button. Icons added with Bootstrap framework are called "glyphicon". Cache teory sounds good. I will check if page source in web browser changes and try other web browsers like opera and chrome

Comment: After shouting down my desktop and server restart the problem ended. I think it was rather browser side, but do not know really. Anyway, thanks.